# Pandas - Comparing column values with value in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
d = {1:a,2:a}
```

I also have a pandas frame "df"

```
0 x y
1 1 10
2 2 56
```

for some reason I can not match up x values with dictionary keys:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for x,y in d.items():
        if row['x'] == x:
            print "Got a Match"
        else:
            print "No Match Found"
```

All I got was "No Match Found". Is there something I am doing wrong? The data in the pandas series was "float64" and the keys were "int" in the dictionary, but I converted the pandas series to int, and still was not able to match these items. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try itertuples instead with the same code

Comment: It works fine for me, what python version are you using?

Comment: Also, what is the ultimate purpose of your problem. It doesn't appear that you need a loop. Can you give more info. And for debugging inside your inner loop, use the print function to get more info: `print(row['x'], x)`

Comment: Python 3.5, Pandas 0.18...The real dataframe and dictionary are much larger. The ultimate purpose is to adjust a different column in the pandas dataframe using the value associated with each key in the dictionary. I am conducting print(row['x'], x) and the numbers are both showing as a match, yet the for loop still does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to create new column based on the dictionary, you can use [`pandas.Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
>>> df['n'] = df['x'].map(d)
>>> df
    x   y     n
1   1  10  val1
2  10  56   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

consider this `df`

```
   x   y
0       
1  1  10
2  2  56
3  3  11
```

and dictionary

```
d = {1: 'a', 2: 'a'}
```

When you use `pd.Series.map` it fills in where it can and returns `NaN` where no key exists.  This can be useful for identifying where `x`'s are matching and to replace values later.

```
df.x.map(d)

0
1      a
2      a
3    NaN
Name: x, dtype: object
```

---

```
d_ = {k: 'Match!' for k, _ in d.items()}
df.x.map(d_).fillna('No Match :-(')

0
1          Match!
2          Match!
3    No Match :-(
Name: x, dtype: object
```